# Java- set relative address for ImageDescriptor

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java plugin. In this plugin, I have a package namely `org.eclipse.epsilon.eol` and in this package I have an image namely `configuration.png`. In the one of the classes of this package I would like to use the below line of code. How can I set the relative address for it?

I tried several things such as `configuration.png`, `eol/configuration.png` and `./eol/configuration.png` but they don't take effect. I also create a folder namely `icon` in the plugin and write `icon/configuration.png` but it doesn't take effect. What should I do?

```
setDefaultPageImageDescriptor(ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(null, "configuration.png"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use relative paths to access resources in plugins (not even the current plugin). When the plugin is packaged as a jar the contents can't be accessed directly as files.

To access resources in a plugin you must use the `FileLocator` API:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("path in the plugin"), null);

ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.